# ionic cordova build android failure after updating firebasex plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I need to update cordova-plugin-firebasex to the latest release, I have gone through the plugin installation and configuration steps here https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#firebase-config-setup.

As of right now i have iOS building correctly and sending analytic data to the firebase console.  however android is currently failing when i attempt to build and i am at a loss of what i am missing.

the build errors i am getting are the following:

````
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:860: error: cannot find symbol
                    handleBooleanTaskOutcome(FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().activate(), callbackContext);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method activate()
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfig
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:872: error: cannot find symbol
                    handleBooleanTaskOutcome(FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().fetchAndActivate(), callbackContext);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method fetchAndActivate()
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfig
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:884: error: cannot find symbol
                    handleTaskOutcome(FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().reset(), callbackContext);
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   method reset()
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfig
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:931: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map<String, FirebaseRemoteConfigValue> nativeValues = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getAll();
                                                                                                            ^
  symbol:   method getAll()
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfig
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:954: error: cannot find symbol
                        settings.setFetchTimeoutInSeconds(args.getLong(0));
                                ^
  symbol:   method setFetchTimeoutInSeconds(long)
  location: variable settings of type Builder
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:958: error: cannot find symbol
                        settings.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(args.getLong(1));
                                ^
  symbol:   method setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(long)
  location: variable settings of type Builder
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:961: error: cannot find symbol
                    handleTaskOutcome(FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setConfigSettingsAsync(settings.build()), callbackContext);
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   method setConfigSettingsAsync(FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings)
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfig
/Users/username/src/mobile-ui/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:973: error: cannot find symbol
                    handleTaskOutcome(FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaultsAsync(defaultsToMap(defaults)), callbackContext);
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   method setDefaultsAsync(Map<String,Object>)
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfig
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors```
````

Comment: Did you try building the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex-test)?

Comment: i did, and that isn't working much better for me